# SAPUI5/Fiori Export to excel -ExportTypeCSV , data formatted prepending a single quote

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am able to export table data to excel dynamically, but some of the data like long numbers and negative values are formatted

Below is the UI Table data
[enter image description here][1]

exported data to CSV
[enter image description here][2]

when I select the long values it showing the proper value on top of excel, and -ve values are appended with '......

Code :

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.Export");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV");
sap.ui.define([
'jquery.sap.global',
'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
"use strict";
var vSrcMATNR;
var oEvtBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
var TableController = Controller.extend("UtilLoad.Util", {
exportToExcel: function(oTable) {
var that = this;
var aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
var aItems = oTable.getItems();
var aTemplate = [];
for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
var oColumn = {
name: aColumns[i].getHeader().getText(),
template: {
content: {
path: null
}
}
};
if (aItems.length > 0) {
oColumn.template.content.path = aItems[0].getCells()[i].getBinding("text").getPath();
}
aTemplate.push(oColumn);
}
var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
// Type that will be used to generate the content. Own ExportType’s can be created to support other formats
exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
separatorChar : ",",
                charset : "utf-8"
}),
// Pass in the model created above
models: oTable.getModel(),
// binding information for the rows aggregation
rows: {
path: "/"
},
// column definitions with column name and binding info for the content
columns: aTemplate
});
oExport.saveFile().always(function() {
this.destroy();
});
},
fnDate: function(sDate) {
if (sDate) {
var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"
});
return oDateFormat.format(new Date(sDate));
} else {
return sDate;
}
}
});
return TableController;
});
```

from SAP documentation advicing to use data export functionality , please what is it and how

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV.html

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: Could you please explain your issue in more detail so that we can be sure to understand your question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnoWl.jpg

Comment: in generated excel negative values are prepended with single quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please convert that numbers into string by giving **Tab Space** between double quotes in the return statement.

```
            {
                name: "Stock",
                template: {
                    content: {
                        parts: ["StockPosition"],
                        formatter: function(value) {

                            return "    " + value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks it works, can you help how can avoid showing longvalues in formaul like 2.85E+12, please find below snap



https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnoWl.jpg

Comment: Yes, in my logic for except the DATE values all other fields  I am applying this formatter

Comment: Out of curiosity, how to implement below excel steps ->rightclick(on column)->format cells->fraction(from catageories)

Answer (score 0):

please find below screen shot 
 [exported excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnoWl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

vH,

Yes,main concern is while transforming data to excel.By appending tab character **(\x09)** I can avoid scientific notation in excel.

Not sure is the best solution or not

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score -1):

Concerning your problem with values being formatted in scientific notation like 2.85E+12:

it is generally not a good idea to deal with **precise** large numbers in JavaScript, because JavaScript uses double precision floating point numbers as defined in the IEEE 754 standard. They lose precision very quickly!

Just try

```
console.log(9999999999999999);
```

the result will be

```
10000000000000000
```

If you want to avoid scientific notation in JavaScript, you have to write your own toString-function by concatenating each digit

```
function convertToString(fNumber){
 var sResult='';
 do{
   var iDigit = fNumber%10;
   fNumber=Math.trunc(fNumber/10);
   sResult = iDigit+sResult;
 }while(fNumber>0)   
 return sResult;
}
```

But your main problem is Excel!

If your csv-file looks like this

```
Customer;Product;EAN;Price
SAP;Hana;1234567890123;1000
SAP;R/3;1234567890124;-1000
SAP;OpenUI5;1234567890126;9999999999999999
```

Excel will show a table that contains scientific notation again!

```
Customer   Product   EAN       Price
SAP        Hana     1,23E+12     1000
SAP        R/3      1,23E+12    -1000
SAP        OpenUI5  1,23E+12   1E+16
```